# Python linking info between modules

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to link info between my modules. At the bottom I will have a summary module that will give the order info at the end of the ordering process to the customer, i.e...email address, address, and items ordered from the menu module. However, I cant seem to figure out how to link between the email module and other modules and my summary module. When I try to run my main module it tells me that email_address is undefined. This is a final project for my programming class and newish to python. This is the email module along with the summary module.

```
import time

def main():

    email(email_address)
    summary(email_address)

def email(email_address):
    email_address = str(input("Please enter a valid email address: "))
    email_address_verify = str(input("Please re-enter your email address: "))
if email_address == email_address_verify:
    print("Thank you!", "\n")
else:
    return email(email_address)
    time.sleep(2)

def summary(email_address):
    print(email_address)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return *email_address* from the **email** function

```
import time

def main():

    email_address = email()
    summary(email_address)

def email():
    email_address = str(input("Please enter a valid email address: "))
    email_address_verify = str(input("Please re-enter your email address: "))
    if email_address == email_address_verify:
        print("Thank you!", "\n")
        return email_address     
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        return email()



def summary(email_address):
    print(email_address)
main()
```

Comment: Thank you! works great now. What if I wanted to call other variables from a module. Say the pay module had both subtotal and total and wanted to call them in the summary module? Thank you.